# Regex to check ending of URL query parameter

Tags: regex

I have following test strings:

1. http://example.com/?foo=bar&path=a/b/c.png/&bar=foo
2. http://example.com/?foo=bar&path=a/b/c.png&bar=foo
3. http://example.com/?foo=bar&path=a/b/c.png
4. http://example.com/?foo=bar&path=a/b/c.png/

I'm looking for a regex that only matches `path=a/b/c.png`(the path query parameter without the trailing slash). The path query parameter can be in the beginning, middle or end of the row.

So far I have following regex `path=[^#&]*`:

You can see it here: https://regex101.com/r/v4DqDx/1/

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: To be more clear, the query parameter in row 1 and 4 with the trailing slash should not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/v4DqDx/7): Uses `m` flag for multiline

```
\bpath=[^#&\n]*\.\w+(?=[&#]|$)
```

If the content is not multiline use this instead:

```
\bpath=[^#&]*\.\w+(?=[&#]|$)
```

---

### Explanation

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary. A word boundary is a location that matches `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`
- `path=` Match this literally
- `[^#&\n]*` Match any character except `#&\n` any number of times
- `\.` Matches a literal dot
- `\w+` Matches one or more word characters
- `(?=[&#]|$)` Positive lookahead ensuring either a character in the set `&#` matches or it's the end of the line.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest did you even read my answer? I specifically put a note for this. I include a link to regex101. This 100% works.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest edited to prevent further confusion. If you wouldn't mind cleaning up your comments after too (to prevent confusion for future viewers)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm looking for a regex that doesn't match the query parameter in row 1 and 4 (ignores the query parameter with a trailing slash).

Comment: @Koji maybe that should've been specified in the question then give me a moment

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you're missing the `m` flag. Why don't you just click on the regex101 link I created to see it in use instead of trying to get it to work yourself?

Comment: Thank you very much @ctwheels!